How to resolve concurrent dependency change?
So let's say I have these variables ($: marks a reactive statement, so when any of the values after = change, the variable is updated):
let x = 0;
$: y = x;
$: z = x + y;

function onSomeUserInteraction(input) {
   y = input;
}

So in this case, x is an independent variable, meanwhile y depends on x, and can also be altered by user interaction. And z depends on x and y.
Now my problem is, that when x changes, this triggers an update in z. But since y depends on x, it also changes, which triggers another, redundant update to z. So my question is, how can I handle these dependencies in such a way that changing x doesn't update z twice? The obvious solution would be just to have $: z = x + x. But the problem is with the user interaction, which might alter the value of y, so y may not always be equal to x.
Another way to reframe the code would be like this:
let x = 0;
$: y = x + i; // I is some arbitrary value that can be updated by the user
$: z = x + y;

Any suggestions for how to resolve this? Thank you.

"which triggers another, redundant update to z." - It doesn't, why do you think it does?

@brunnerh Hmm you're right, I just tested on a REPL. I guess it's either because I'm using an outdated version of Svelte which hasn't patched this bug, or something to do with having complex object structures in my code (this question was simplified)

You can declare your variable non-reactively and use a reactive effect to update your value where you explicitly tell Svelte what variable triggers the effect, like this:
<script>
    let x = 0;
    $: y = x;
    let z = x + y;

    // If `y` changes, update `z`. 
    $: y, z = x + y;
    
  /* This way `x` doesn't update `z` directly, 
   instead it reactively updates `y` 
   which in turn triggers the `z` update */
    
    function onSomeUserInteraction(input) {
        y = input;
    }
</script>


